# MS Detours 3.0 on Win 7 x64?

Tags: hook, detours

I want to get into detail with win api hooking. This is a cite from the download page of MS Detours 3.0:

> Detours Express 3.0 is available for immediate download under a no-fee, click-through license for research, non-commercial, and non-production use.  Detours Express is limited to 32-bit processes on x86 processors.

I am using Win 7 x64. Is that meaning that Detours (at least the free version) is useless for me? I ask because I read a lot of post recommendnig MS Detours, but nowadays i think nearly everyone is working on an x64 machine.

Has anybody worked with it on an x64 OS? Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Detours x64 is a commercial package which is very expensive.  an alternative is MHook,
or EasyHook.

Comment: Make sure to use apriorit's fork of Mhook (https://github.com/apriorit/mhook), it has lots of improvements and bug fixes that are not merged back to the original Mhook project.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recently [released](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours) under the MIT license.
It includes support for x86, x64, IA64 and ARM architectures as well as some [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/wiki/Samples).

Answer (score 0):

i write a tool D Probe, support both x86/x64 hooking, but it's not a hook library, it's a dynamic tracing tool with a API filter SDK, so it must be integrated into D Probe console, can not be linked into other application as independent module as detours or easyhook, if you want to have a try, go to my profile page to get the download link.